# Compute dual graph from polygons

Tags: algorithm, graph, geometry, computational-geometry, planar-graph

### Task

Compute the dual graph from a set of non-overlapping (but touching) polygons.

### Example

Polygons *A*, *B* and *C*, their partially shared coordinates 1—22 (yellow) and the dual graph (blue).

[image: Polygons and their dual graph]

### Data

I have a set *S* of polygons. Every polygon *P*<sub>*i*</sub> is represented as ordered list of coordinates. The edge *a* — *b* of a polygon *P*<sub>*i*</sub> is denoted by *P<sub>i,(a,b)</sub>*

### Idea

The polygons represent the faces and hence the nodes of the dual graph. To identify adjacent faces of the polygon *P<sub>i</sub>* just compare every edge of *P<sub>i</sub>* with every edge of every other polygon *P<sub>j</sub>*. If the edge is shared by the other polygon then *P<sub>i</sub>* and *P<sub>j</sub>* are adjacent.

This will create a significant amount of multiple edges which can be removed later.

### Problem

The algorithm is not very efficient as it runs in *O(E<sup>2</sup>)* where *E* denotes the number of edges of the set *S* of polygons.

### Improvement ideas

Create an edge-index in a first-step. This will reduce running-time to *O(2×E)* = *O(E)*

Remove every node with degree 2. (I think this won't affect the dual graph?)

### Questions

- Am I on the right track?
- Are there any approved algorithms for this task?

Comment: I'd the purpose of the algorithm to find adjacent polygons (is *that* the required output)?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Is the graph planar?

Comment: Yes, the polygons don't overlap, they only touch. Hence, the graph is planar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a map from edge (as key) to polygon in *O(n)* time. Iterate all edges of all polygons (order is not important) and insert values into the map. When inserting a new value, if the key already exists, you've found an adjacent polygon - put this polygon pair in a set. When you're done, the set holds all adjacent polygon pairs.